# Download generated HTML file

Tags: java, download, vaadin

I have a generated HTML file which I need to be able to download at the click of a button (so not opening in a new window, just showing the save file dialog for this particular html file).

The code I have so far:

```
AVaadinApplication application = VaadinContext.getCurrentInstance().getVariable(VaadinContext.APPLICATION, AVaadinApplication.class);

StreamResource inputHTML = new StreamResource(
        new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public InputStream getStream() {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(getHelpContentString(getLocale()).getBytes());
            }
        }, "help_" + getLocale() + ".html", application);
 inputHTML.setCacheTime(0);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been breaking my head on this.

Comment: "The code I have so far:" - what's the actual problem? Does it not work? Are you unsure where to go next? Do you get errors? Please be more specific.

Comment: The code works as in it generates the HTML file required but it only opens it in a new tab (when called with `getMainWindow().open(inputHTML, "_blank");`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the HTML in a Zip file.  No browser I know will attempt to display a Zip file, but instead push it out as a file to 'Open (in a Zip archive program) or Save'.

Comment: No worries.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You should set the HTTP `Content-Disposition` header of the result to attachment.  How you do that depends on how you interact with the web server.  Are yore code running as a servlet, in the play framwork, as a cgi, etc?